# display images from database to blade in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I have a database where images are stored in the table row like this:

```
name(string)        "name"
sometext(string)    "some description"
filesnames(string)  image1.jpeg|image2.jpeg
```

image1 and image2 are stored in the "public/storage/image" folder

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $data = request()->validate([
        'name' => 'required',
        'sometext' => '',
        'testImages' => '',
        'testImages' => 'image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg|max:2048',
    ]);

    $images = array();
    
    if($files = $request->file('testImages')){
        foreach($files as $file){
            $name = $file->getClientOriginalName();
            $file->move('image', $name);
            $images[] = $name;
        }
    }

    auth()->user()->tests()->create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'sometext' => $data['sometext'],
        'filenames' => implode("|", $images),
    ]);
}

public function show ($id)
{
    $tests = Tests::findorfail($id);  //get row data from table with ID
    return view('test.show-report', compact('tests'));  //return data to blade
}
```

In blade I am able to do a `$tests->name` and `$tests->description` to get data successfully.

I am unable to figure out how to display images from "filenames" blade.

Comment: What is the exact content in the database cell? image1.jpeg? How did you manage to upload them?

Comment: I have updated store function as well in the description

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do like so:

```
@foreach(explode('|',$tests->filenames) as $fileName)
    <img src="/storage/image/{{$fileName}}"/>
@endforeach
```

Comment: No problem, just mark it as the answer so its helpful to others as well

Answer (score 0):

try like this
`<img src="/storage/image/{{ $tests['filenames'] }}" height="30px" width="30px" />`
hope it will help:
In This case:
In controller use explode() to $tests->filenames make an array and then loop it like this

```
@foreach(json_decode($tests->filenames, true) as $images)
     <img src="/storage/image/{{ $images }}" height="30px" width="30px" />
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

If the images names are stored properly in the database with the correct extension, here's what you are going to need in your blade view:

```
  <img src="/storage/image/{{$tests->NAME_OF_COLUMN_IN_DB}}" />
```

just replace "NAME_OF_COLUMN_IN_DB" with the column name where you store the image name in your database.

Comment: NAME_OF_COLUMN_DB has multiple image names like image.jpeg|image2.jpeg (separated with | ) can you please help me how could I display two images in blade.

Comment: If you're storing multiple image names inside one row you cant store them as a text and retrieve them into your views, you need to either store one image name in one db row or to store all image names as JSON which has a different way to handle.

Answer (score 0):

Use like this

```
<img src="{{ url('') }}/storage/image/{{$tests-> filenames}}">
```

Answer (score 0):

In Your Model Write a function like this. Suppose you are in User Model.

```
    public function getImage()
{
    return isset($this->image) && $this->image ? asset('userPhoto/'.$this->image): asset("dist/img/user2-160x160.jpg");
}
```

Now retrive the image in the blade file like this-

```
<a href="{{asset('userPhoto/'.$user->image)}}"target="_blank">
<img src="{{ $user->getImage() }}"width="50"></a>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can follow the procedure below

```
<img src="{{ public_path('storage\image') }}{{ $tests->filenames }}" alt=""/>
```

Use the following code to separate the names of the images

```php
$img = exploade('|', $tests->filenames);
dump($img);
```

Comment: Please check your code. Why is there a backslash in the path name? And what does `exploade` do?

Comment: for get url. and exploade for convert string to array. sample "img1.jpg|img2.png" How do I separate this string?